# website images not showing up on ipad

Tags: wordpress, ipad

I am fairly new to web design but managing so far because of sites like this. My latest website (a Wordpress Twentyeleven child theme) looks great on my pc in chrome, firefox etc but when I look at it on my ipad all the images display as boxes with grey borders: images in the header, footer and posts don't display. But images placed with css (as backgrounds) and images  from my NextGen gallery work fine. I'm learning how to use media styles so I thought maybe that was it so I deleted them all and refreshed the site but it made no difference.
Any help is much appreciated!
http://viperformance.ca/viperformance
(still testing, which is why the new site is in another folder)

I am so confused.

PS. I do have some flash files on there and I know they won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you are pointing your images to `localhost`

try checking the source code on the browser... it has something like this `http://localhost/viperformance/wp-content/themes/VIPCustom/images/facebook.png`

if you have it on php file... change all images `src` to something like this

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/facebook.png" />`

Comment: thanks, I can't believe I overlooked that, I had problems running a search and replace string...